# add feature is disabled tfs2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I just enabled the feature portfolio on my backlog and the add button is disabled. The only way to add Feature is with an extension that I found, but it's not a good solution for me.  How can I enable adding Feature on my backlog?

I'm currently using tfs2017.1 on premise

Comment: What do you mean? Can you add a screenshot? Exact error message? Which backlog level are you on?

Comment: Can't add asscreenshot unfortunately, and there is no error message. My backlog level is Features. The add button there is disable and I can't add title as well

Comment: I can add that on other projects adding Features are enabled. So something is not OK with this project. I didn't know what to change At the XML

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the `addpanel` in the `processconfiguration.xml`:

This is the default from the Aile template

```
<PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Features" singularName="Feature" parent="Microsoft.EpicCategory" workItemCountLimit="1000">
  <States>
    <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
    <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
  </States>
  <Columns>
    <Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" />
    <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" />
    <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
    <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" width="50" />
    <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" width="50" />
    <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" />
    <Column refname="System.Tags" width="200" />
  </Columns>
  <AddPanel>
    <Fields>
      <!-- Make sure all required fields in state new are listed here -->
      <Field refname="System.Title" />
    </Fields>
  </AddPanel>
</PortfolioBacklog>
```

Comment: when i add <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" width="50" /> and  <Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" /> i got tf400529

Comment: Check: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e22aec1c-ae36-4590-848c-19c01a4ae9d2/issue-configuring-features-after-upgrading-from-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2015?forum=tfsprocess